# Bash Integer Comparison

Tags: bash, test

While reading through a bash style guide I found the following guideline:

> #### Math / Integer Manipulation
>
> Use `((...))` and `$((...))`.

```
a=5
b=4

# wrong
if [[ $a -gt $b ]]; then
    ...
fi

# right
if ((a > b)); then
    ...
fi
```

When I inquired about the reasoning I was told that the `[[` test could potentially choke trying to compare numbers with leading zeros.  In my testing I have not been able to recreate this issue.

**My Question**

> Is there actually a functional difference between `((a > b))` and `[[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I can see.

But there is a difference between `[[ val1 < val2 ]]` and `(( val1 < val2 ))`: the former is a string comparison.

```
$ [[ 2 -lt 007 ]] && echo true || echo false
true
$ [[ 2 < 007 ]] && echo true || echo false
false
$ (( 2 < 007 )) && echo true || echo false
true
```

Though leading zeroes are still a problem in both cases:

```
$ (( 20 < 021 )) && echo true || echo false
false
$ [[ 20 -lt 021 ]] && echo true || echo false
false
```

That's because they mark octal numbers, as in C. But you prevent that by prefixing them with `10#`. ([Bash Reference 6.5 Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic))

```
$ (( 10#20 < 10#021 )) && echo true || echo false
true
```

Comment: @fpmurphy1, Well, I don't think I'm that interested in continuing this argument. You can post your own answer to argue your point, if you wish.